# How do I import a mysql database to firebase and push notifications to the user's phone, everytime a record is inserted to a table in real time?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `MySQL` file that I want to import into Firebase Realtime Database. My `MySQL` file contains a database, which contains a table. Every time a record is inserted into the table, I want to push a notification to my app on the user's phone in real-time. How do I proceed?

Comment: From which database do you want a notification (MySQL or Firebase)?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a MySQL file that I want to import into Firebase Realtime Database.

There is no way you can import a MySQL file into the Firebase console. You need to write code for that. So you should create your own mechanism that reads the data in the MySQL file and add it to the Realtime Database.

> My MySQL file contains a database, which contains a table. Every time a record is inserted into the table, I want to push a notification to my app on the user's phone in real-time.

Once you add all the data from the MySQL file into the Realtime Database, you can then use [Cloud Function for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), to send a notification in response to the addition of an element in the database.

Comment: Hey Abhishek. Can I help you with other information?